# Dynamic ORDER BY clause in PL/SQL cursor

Tags: oracle-10g

I am not sure if this is simply impossible or if I need to approach this from a different angle.

Simplified, here is what I am trying:

```
create or replace FUNCTION someFunction(SortCol1 varchar2 default 'column1',
                                        SortDir1 varchar2 default 'ASC')
RETURN STUFF pipelined
AS
CURSOR c1 is
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        table1
    ORDER BY
        SortCol1 SortDir1;

BEGIN
    FOR c1_rec IN c1
    LOOP
        -- Some logic, etc...
    END LOOP;
END someFunction;
```

Upon compiling this simply tells me that my SQL is improperly terminated. It does not like the `SortCol1 SortDir1`

Comment: different order by clause, different sql query, different execution plan. You have to use dynamic sql. `OPEN CURSOR FOR`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dynamically change the column you're sorting by using static SQL.  You'd need to use dynamic SQL.  Something like this should work

```
create or replace FUNCTION someFunction(SortCol1 varchar2 default 'column1',
                                        SortDir1 varchar2 default 'ASC')
RETURN STUFF pipelined
AS
    c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
    c1_rec table1%rowtype;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1
     FOR 'select * from table1 order by ' || sortCol1 || ' ' || sortDir1;

    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO c1_rec;  

        <<do something>>
    END LOOP;

END someFunction;
```

Comment: This looks like it could work for me, quick question though. I plan to have a total of 5 sortable columns so I'll go sortCol1 - sortCol5. Does dynamic SQL support ternary operators or do I have to use string concatenation via a variable and `IF` blocks?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - Dynamic SQL depends on building up a SQL statement as a string and executing it.  I can't think of a ternary operator that SQL or PL/SQL supports off the top of my head.  You can pass any number of bind variable values in with a dynamic SQL statement but you can't bind column names, just values.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will work on getting your example to work in my current function and hopefully I can accept your answer :)